# In Chrome Devtools Protocol, what is `injectedScriptId`?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

In CDP, when, for example, executing [Debugger.evaluateOnCallFrame](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Debugger#method-evaluateOnCallFrame) in order to evaluate some object, the response will contain an `objectId` property that looks like `{injectedScriptId: 1, id: 413}`. And the `injectedScriptId` never changes (at least I've never observed it changed). The `id` prop seems to be a unique object id in the memory.

Related (even more important, but simply seeking confirmation) question: is the `id` in `objectId` a unique identifier of the object across the whole program/process? Can I rely on it in order to build a serialized, circular-reference-free string representation of variables?

So what's the purpose of the `injectedScriptId` and what is `InjectedScript`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer from JoelEinbinder](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol/issues/169#issuecomment-499760753):

> This is an internal implementation detail so you shouldn’t rely on it
>   and it may change at any time without warning, or not behave
>   consistently.
>
> Injected script is the internal thing that we inject into a JavaScript
>   execution context to manage remote objects and other things. That’s
>   why they have separate id counters.
>
> So no, the internal id is not unique. Use the string.